# Routing issue in Angular 7 PWA

Tags: angular

I am working on PWA routing.

My application have lots of routing such as /login, /sales, dashboard, etc

When I go offline application is not loaded.

If I run through `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/<project-name>` then it works but not in live server.

Here is my code for reference

**1. ngsw.json**

```
{
  "configVersion": 1,
  "timestamp": 1584503078217,
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [
        "/10.0f66ae0fae218533f9a6.js",
        "/5.19dbe892e2e8aadba21c.js",
        "/6.1d98e75cca8b34ff9526.js",
        "/7.e72aa2f85deba2a48106.js",
        "/8.901d825bd38dcacfeedc.js",
        "/9.c9d3393786dbf6e57fa0.js",
        "/es2015-polyfills.bda95d5896422d031328.js",
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/main.9857e4022adeb074a1f1.js",
        "/polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js",
        "/runtime.a99a399885c62d2de397.js",
        "/scripts.9698794fec8bbc1150b6.js",
        "/styles.5d0c3c7aa71f52e8af72.css"
      ],
      "patterns": []
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [
        "/assets/config/endpoints.json",
        "/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
        "/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
        "/assets/img/kot-token-icon.png",
        "/assets/img/pos-logo-login.png",
        "/assets/img/pos-logo.png",
        "/assets/img/table-icon.png",
        "/assets/js/barcode.min.js",
        "/assets/language/ar.json",
        "/assets/language/de-de.json",
        "/assets/language/en-gb.json",
        "/assets/language/hi.json"
      ],
      "patterns": []
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [],
  "hashTable": {
    "/10.0f66ae0fae218533f9a6.js": "42926b31df58fbd26c5d7bbb39cb93cabed5bc5d",
    "/5.19dbe892e2e8aadba21c.js": "df26cc23773829c08bed420d8d6f7de13b373e6d",
    "/6.1d98e75cca8b34ff9526.js": "1bd68568f462832133e53768411665e9eea23d3c",
    "/7.e72aa2f85deba2a48106.js": "b2389fd7042d23e3eea37a37ce688600d49a4c5f",
    "/8.901d825bd38dcacfeedc.js": "bffec044cc20ac0e31b817b0e87dcd16e51c0234",
    "/9.c9d3393786dbf6e57fa0.js": "f965cea6e6725cf356e2c89b47095d76214f286e",
    "/assets/config/endpoints.json": "3ae2d20477e108733af53ac2c7c66d31a9b971e5",
    "/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png": "6a310f1f738959788b29a1e3f4a7685dce242852",
    "/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png": "1b47e7f77bb0e549618c6edafe132808e1d861ee",
    "/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png": "8a404d58b3c97810fd4b4c455522e78db706f21d",
    "/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png": "49878171f9a862944189d94589fb71356915b7b5",
    "/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png": "9a55c73f98a3e00d6bf98d4271812b9b39384773",
    "/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png": "9a55c73f98a3e00d6bf98d4271812b9b39384773",
    "/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png": "accf7305822b1eff11e45e9d28c483095a8190e6",
    "/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png": "afc0b48a647e612d82ecb9ce60d3a2feb9c42d68",
    "/assets/img/kot-token-icon.png": "402506eb87e2b869b811420f3cb9d02ed9bfd0a9",
    "/assets/img/table-icon.png": "db635b12f42a53045acf46ffc71da8fec1480687",
    "/assets/js/barcode.min.js": "7eeb9a75673e5b52993ac577bb7249e18a27a7ef",
    "/assets/language/ar.json": "88fdbc4d4a275b2a1ca571de9fce922e0d7a5258",
    "/assets/language/de-de.json": "753097a1f3b3a15a8b22907f85ff8db7f1c8cb68",
    "/assets/language/en-gb.json": "20ba419d2566fe6b540f644681fc52f7c5a7fc71",
    "/assets/language/hi.json": "88b06d38814fdae0f6df0504fc553529ea3fdc27",
    "/es2015-polyfills.bda95d5896422d031328.js": "1612fe8f7e8e0c856f0885ff179e93363c67834f",
    "/favicon.ico": "8e898ac808d961aed3d195e4610eb3b9404e2134",
    "/index.html": "2f119ea31bed09cfb044ff07628de2a08f18643e",
    "/main.9857e4022adeb074a1f1.js": "86fc0921ae548bd0a9a728e2b3244d5bd0c118c1",
    "/polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js": "ffa449995bf2eba2ccd0a002417214f7eb75e7b5",
    "/runtime.a99a399885c62d2de397.js": "37d8b34e7e7e8a74a9d5fab41ef46f4ccacf23ae",
    "/scripts.9698794fec8bbc1150b6.js": "21419be8bdabfb1a9f9240738ddb1c51be249eac",
    "/styles.5d0c3c7aa71f52e8af72.css": "245212602f3098dba38d227a9c975cb8b01ff056"
  },
  "navigationUrls": [
    {
      "positive": true,
      "regex": "^\\/.*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*\\.[^/]*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*\\/.*$"
    }
  ]
}
```

**2. manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "short_name": "demo",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have https enabled in the live server?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan
 yes, I have https server. 
let me explain the issue. 
I have routes in my application 

ex: 
xyz.com/login
xyz.com/home
xyz.com/dashboard

like this.

If I run my application in my local system by running command 

ng build --prod
http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/projectname

it works perfectly in offline mode. But when I deploy same build in live https server it worsk in online but not in offline.

Hope I have shared concerened enough to make you understand. If possible please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to set the baseHref in the angular.json, baseHref was being set previously only in the index.html.

```
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "baseHref": "/c/",
            "ngswConfigPath": "projects/consumer/ngsw-config.json"
```

Not it appears to work as expected. Hopefully this helps someone else.